# Hibernate @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Here is my problem

`IdComposite` class:

```
@Embeddable
public class IdComposite implements Serializable{

 @Column(name = "code1", nullable = false)
 private String code1;

 @Column(name = "code2", nullable = false)
 private String code2;

// getters, setters, hashCode & equals

}
```

`MyEntity` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class MyEntity {

 @EmbeddedId
 private IdComposite comId;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {})
 @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
 private A a;

 // constructors, getters setters, e t.c.

}
```

`DaoClass` fragment:

```
MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
A a = new A();
a.setId(5);
myEntity.setA(a);
IdComposite id = new IdComposite();
id.setCode1("1");
id.setCode2("2");
myEntity.setComId(id);
getSession().save(myEntity);
```

Hibernate result:

> Hibernate: insert into table (code1, code2) values (?, ?) SQL Error:
>   1400, SQLState: 23000 ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
>   "table"."a_id")

What is wrong?

**Edited:**

Ok, I've changed the code in that way:

`MyEntity` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class MyEntity {

 @EmbeddedId
 private IdComposite comId;

 @Column(name = "a_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
 private Long aId;

 // constructors, getters setters, e t.c.

}
```

`DaoClass` fragment:

```
MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
Long aId = 5L;
A a = (A) getSession().get(A.class, aId);
if (a == null || a.getId() != 5) { return }
myEntity.setAId(a.getId());
IdComposite id = new IdComposite();
id.setCode1("1");
id.setCode2("2");
myEntity.setComId(id);
getSession().save(myEntity);
```

Hibernate result:

> Hibernate: insert into table (code1, code2) values (?, ?)
>   SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
>   ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TABLE"."A_ID")

**Solved**

The problem was here:

```
, insertable = false)
```

So, hibernate generate sql without a_id field that caused error

Comment: You are not cascading the save operation to the A class. If you don't want to use cascading, you should save your A entity before saving myEntity

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems to come from composite id, but from A. try to save A instance

```
MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
A a = new A();
a.setId(5);
a= getSession().save(a);
myEntity.setA(a);
IdComposite id = new IdComposite();
id.setCode1("1");
id.setCode2("2");
myEntity.setComId(id);
getSession().save(myEntity);
```

Comment: A instance saved (sorry, I missed it in fragment). It seems like SQL is wrong. Look, hibernate try to insert only 2 fields. "insert into table (code1, code2)..." Where is "a_id" in query?

Comment: I think hibernate try to flush previous command before next insert, this is why you get error from previous command and therefore "cannot insert NULL into "table"."a_id")".  Can you update your question with the full code ?